# MapView not rendered in Android emulator. "Unfortunately, Expo has stopped." error occured

Tags: react-native, google-maps, android-emulator, expo, android-mapview

Im trying to run the example listed in https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view in an android emulator inside expo.
But it doesn't work, and crashed every time with the message "Unfortunately, Expo has stopped."
I would very much appreciate your help on getting MapView to display properly on the Android emulator.

Comment: You mean this one? https://snack.expo.io/@charliecruzan/basicmapviewexample It runs without problem for me. Are you still getting that error atm?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. It was just because of the wrong google API key.
I'd like to post details as an answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks for your update and for sharing your solution with the community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works well. It was just because of incorrect google API key.

But there's no displayed detail error info, and just crashed, so I was not sure and very confused about what the problem is.

At the last, I switched my project into a Flutter, and doing the same functions, I found that my API key was wrong. So I returned to React Native Expo again and typed the correct API key and made the project work well.

What I did are the following 2 things.
1. Generated a google API key for map SDK for android according to the following link.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key
2. Typed the API key to the app.json file.

Any doubts, let me know, please.
Thanks.